# How can this error ("TypeError: popover is not a function"), preventing a graph from loading, be solved?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, web2py, metricsgraphicsjs

**update**: It appears that everything has been solved by including the bootstrap.min.js in the html file itself (even though the bootstrap file is extended from layout, it must have been included after the other dependent scripts are, as its components weren't being accessed by them). I'll post as an answer when I can unless someone else can do so (I may not understand the problem as well as you).

I'm trying to use Web2py to test a simple [MetricsGraphics example](http://www.metricsgraphicsjs.org/interactive-demo.htm), but no graph loads in the browser.

Current error preventing graph from being displayed:

`TypeError: $(args.target+' h2.chart_title').popover is not a function. (In '$(args.target+' h2.chart_title').popover', '$(args.target+' h2.chart_title').popover' is undefined)`

The error occurs in metricsgraphics.min.js

HTML file:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="{{=URL('static','js/d3/d3.min.js')}}"></script>

<link href="{{=URL('static','js/metric-graphics/css/metricsgraphics.css')}}" rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
<script src="{{=URL('static','js/metric-graphics/js/metricsgraphics.min.js')}}"></script>


<h3>Graph</h3>

<div class="result text-center col-xs-5">

<script>
 data_graphic({
  title: "UFO Sightings",
  description: "Yearly UFO sightings from 1945 to 2010.",
  data: [{'year':1964, 'sightings':6}] // JSON.parse({{=sample}}), // also tried as JSON.parse([{"year":1945, "sightings":"6"}])
  markers: [{'year': 1964, 'label': '"The Creeping Terror" released'}],
  width: 600,
  height: 250,
  target: ".result",
  x_accessor: "year",
  y_accessor: "sightings",
});
</script>
{{#=BEAUTIFY(response._vars)}}
```

Python controller function:

```
def chart_view():
    '''This will show the graph for a feed (axes)'''

    # sample = [{"year": "1945", "count": 6}, {"year": "1950", "sightings": 35}, {"year": "1964", "sightings": 6}]

    return dict()
```

Comment: You'll need to give more details. According to the web2py docs, anything decorated with `service.json` is exposed as a web endpoint that returns JSON. So how are you calling that service? Where are you expecting `{{ sample }}` to come from? Where is the controller that is rendering that view?

Comment: That's a good reminder. I probably shouldn't be using service.json then. But I still receive the error when returning json via json.loads() without service.json. I may be misreading the question, but `sample` should be made available in the html titled the same as the controller function when it's returned from that function.

Comment: ...and I don't believe it's an access problem with the controller, as the controller file default.py is in the controllers folder, and the view is accessed relative to it, so I would be getting another error.

Comment: But you still need to show how `sample` is getting into that view. Is it being populated at all? What can you see in View source for that line?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see it at all because it won't load the page as it looks like it's a browser error. Although I know it loads the page without the line... so I'll try to find another way to see what {{sample}} generates.

Comment: After removing `sample`, and just placing `JSON.parse('[{"year":1945, "sightings":"6"}]')` in the data line, there is no error (for whatever reason it couldn't use the data from `sample`), but there is no graph on the page.

Comment: In another test, I returned `sample` as  `'[{"year": "1945", "sightings:6"}]'`, and the only thing printed in the browser was [{"year": "1945", "sightings:6"}] when parsing as `JSON.parse({{sample}})`

Answer (score 1):

To write a Python object into a view, it must be preceded by an equals sign:

```
{{=sample}}
```

There may be other errors, as it is not clear how you are getting `sample` to that view.

Comment: This helps, but I'll update the question since the main issue of the non-existent graph remains. I'm now seeing errors in the console with the blank page that I'll review when possible.

Comment: I now suspect this may have to do with my Web2py formatting, as there are no errors, and the only thing printed on the page is [{"year":1945, "sightings":"6"}]

Comment: It was found that by returning sample, the plain data text was printed, so for now I'm only returning dict(). I'm pretty lost on how to solve the current error. The post was edited to include it.